# Bash quoting of current path (pwd)

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

I have encountered a most annoying problem that occurs on the [PWD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174990/what-is-pwd-vs-current-working-directory) variable when the current path includes a space. My code looks somewhat like this:

```
mycommand |sed -E '
 s|mystuff|replacement| ;
 s|'$(pwd)'|replacement| ;
 '
```

This works great, unless the current path contains a space character. If it does, `$(pwd)` is expanded to

```
'mypath/with space'
```

instead of just

```
mypath/with space
```

This cause the sed expression to be messed up (because of the extra quotes):

```
sed: 1: "s|mypath/with": unterminated substitute pattern
```

I have noticed that it doesn't help to expand pwd like this: `${PWD//\'/}`.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Is that really the command? Variables aren't expanded inside single-quotes, so I can't see how $(pwd) in the above would be getting expanded at all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've added the missing quotes.

Comment: Have you tried using the equivalent environment variable ($PWD) instead of command substitution to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: As is explained in the question, yes. The contents of the variable is what is returned by the pwd command (including the single-quotes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace single quotes by double quotes and replace quotes with backquotes around pwd:

```
mycommand | sed -E "
 s|mystuff|replacement| ;
 s|`pwd`|replacement| ;
"
```

Double quotes allow expansion of variables and backquoted commands.

Comment: You used a variable where the OP used command substitution, but it works if you change it to match (or if you use it as is in the appropriate situation).

Comment: This will not work, as $(pwd) will be expanded to 'mypath/with space', which won't match in the sed expression. If I used ${PWD//\'/} this would work, though.

Comment: @Ludvig: I'm not getting the single quotes when I try this.

Comment: The point about command substitution instead of variable substitution is correct. I update my answer accordingly.

Comment: To be clear, the solution is to use double-quotes around the sed expression, and to use the PWD environment variable, removing single-quotes, instead of the pwd builtin which will produce single-quotes still:
mycommand | sed -E " s|${PWD//\'/}|replacement "

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
'$(pwd)'
```

with

```
'"$(pwd)"'
```

It would look like this then:

```
mycommand | sed -E '  
 s|mystuff|replacement| ;  
 s|'"$(pwd)"'|replacement| ;  
 '
```

Comment: You have a double quote out of place in the line following "with"

Comment: oh well... may i have an old version of sed? i don't even have the option -E, only -e. I've checked using the following command:

    echo PART1$(pwd)PART2| sed -e 's|PART1|replaced| ; s|'"$(pwd)"'|PATH|;' ;

and the output is

    replacedPATHPART2

Comment: No, compare the line I mentioned with the next-to-last line. It's just a typo.